# sed delete match within quotes on line containing several quotes

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a file called names.xml

That looks like the below:

```
    NAME="Stacey" SURNAME="Ford"  
    blah blah blah  
    NAME="Stacey" SURNAME="Ford"  
    blah blah blah
```

I need to find all occurrences of NAME=" and with the "" quotes I need to replace the name with another value.

So the output needs to look like this:

```
    NAME="Jack" SURNAME="Ford"  
    blah blah blah  
    NAME="Jack" SURNAME="Ford"  
    blah blah blah
```

I am using: `sed 's/NAME=".*"/NAME="Jack"/g' names.xml`

But this is the result it gives me:

```
    NAME="Jack"  
    blah blah blah  
    NAME="Jack"  
    blah blah blah
```

It is looking at everything up until the last " on SURNAME.

Your time and assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a negated character class `[^"]*` which matches any character but not of `"` zero or more times. `.*` in your regex is greedy by default, it eats all the characters upto the last `"` double quotes. So that only it matches `Stacey` and upto the last `Ford`. And also you must need to add a word boundary `\b` before the `NAME`, so that it won't match the string `NAME` in `SURNAME` . `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character.

```
sed 's/\bNAME="[^"]*"/NAME="Jack"/g' names.xml
```

Comment: This does't work,it also matches surname, you should remove the `g`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `awk` version:

```
awk -F\" -vOFS=\" '$1~/NAME=/ {$2="Jack"}1' file
    NAME="Jack" SURNAME="Ford"
    blah blah blah
    NAME="Jack" SURNAME="Ford"
    blah blah blah
```

Use `"` as field separator.  If field `1` contains `NAME=` replace filed `2` with `Jack` and print it.